# Node display mode on taxonomy page

Tags: theming, nodes, taxonomy-terms

How do you choose the display mode for a node that is used on an taxonomy page?

As default the nodes are displayed using the node-teaser mode but i would like to create a custom style for nodes that are show a taxonomy page.

I could change the teaser mode to what i need but then that would be changed on every place the teaser view is used.

Answer (score 4):

You can change this be enabling the Taxonomy Term View (I suggest cloning it in case you mess something up) and then you can change the view to suit your needs.

Comment: No way to do this with just the display suite?

Comment: None that I'm aware of.  I haven't used DS much, but Drupal core is handling the taxonomy/term page and the only way I know of doing that without overriding core would be a view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [taxonomy term display](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display) which also plays well with ds.

When you enable this module you can reuse the core functionality of Drupal or either change them completely using the ds module.